# VBA HTML Navigate Through Listings

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I've got the following code that WORKS, and pulls all of the links for listings in the webpage below.  I am now looking to expand this to pull the next page of results (up to n).  I took a stab at doing this (second half of this code), but nothing is being displayed.

NOTE:  In this sample of code, I was attempting to place the second page of links in Column B, but in an ideal world, I'd like to add the links to the bottom of the results of Page 1 (in Column A).

UPDATE: This code now moves to each page result, but it pastes the same links in Col A as B as C, etc. I am not sure how this is happening as I can watch the browser changing URLs as it goes.

Also, if you have any better ways of doing this (rather than copy/pasting this 10x to get the amount of results I am looking for), please let me know!

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLinks()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet, t As Date
Dim k As Integer
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ie
    .Visible = True
k = 0
Do While k < 10
    .Navigate2 "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iPhone&_sacat=0&_ipg=200&_pgn=" & k

    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim Links As Object, i As Long, count As Long
    t = Timer
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Links = .Document.querySelectorAll(".s-item__link[href]")
        count = Links.Length
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop While count = 0
    For i = 0 To Links.Length - 1
        ws.Cells(i + 1, k + 1) = Links.item(i)
    Next
    k = k + 1
Loop

    .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably look to add in a test to ensure the number of pages you request are not greater than the available. Modularize the code a little to pull out the info extraction step. Use arrays and some basic optimization (Screenupdating) to speed up the whole process. Also, get rid of the ie object asap.

This with the listings  results count set to 200 (which in fact gives 211 results per page with the given selector). Not sure if this is simply an ebay setting that is remembered or is default.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, nodeList As Object, page As Long, totalResults As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Const RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 211
    Const DESIRED_PAGES = 3
    Const BASE = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iPhone&_sacat=0&_ipg=200&_pgn="
    Dim results(), url As String, maxPages As Long
    ReDim results(1 To DESIRED_PAGES)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        For page = 1 To DESIRED_PAGES
            url = BASE & page
            .Navigate2 url
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            If page = 1 Then
                totalResults = Replace$(.document.querySelector(".srp-controls__count-heading").innerText, " results", vbNullString)
                maxPages = totalResults / RESULTS_PER_PAGE
            End If
            Set nodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("#srp-river-results .s-item__link[href]")
            results(page) = GetLinks(nodeList)
            Set nodeList = Nothing
            If page + 1 >= maxPages Then Exit For
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    If maxPages < DESIRED_PAGES Then ReDim Preserve results(1 To maxPages)
    For page = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
        If page = 1 Then
            ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(results(page), 1)) = Application.Transpose(results(page))
        Else
            ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(results(page), 1)) = Application.Transpose(results(page))
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetLinks(ByVal nodeList As Object) As Variant
    Dim results(), i As Long
    ReDim results(1 To nodeList.Length)
    For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
        results(i + 1) = nodeList.item(i)
    Next
    GetLinks = results
End Function

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Overwhelmingly Impressive @QHarr!!! I'm still scared to see the usage of array, though.

Comment: @sim Thanks. What frustrated me is that it seems I am being throttled with XMLHTTP. I set up a class but as soon as I went more than 2 pages the whole thing stalled :-(

Answer (score 2):

Untested (and I might be missing something), but seems like you can just specify the page you want to access with URL query parameter `_pgn`.

So for example, navigating to the URL below:

`https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=iPhone&_sacat=0&_ipg=200&_pgn=2`

means you're requesting page 2 (also, the `_ipg` parameter seems to dictate how many results are shown on a page, so increasing to `200` might mean you need to make fewer requests overall).

So if you create some variable `pageNumber` in your code and increment it inside some sort of loop (that terminates once you've reached the last page), you should be able to get all pages -- or even any page at some arbitrary index --without copy-pasting/repeating yourself in your code.

Comment: Thanks!  I've updated the code to incorporate this..  This code now moves to each page result, but it pastes the same links in Col A as B as C, etc. I am not sure how this is happening as I can watch the browser changing URLs as it goes.  Thoughts?

Comment: @RCarmody, consider setting `Links` to `Nothing` and `count` to `0` after this line `k = k + 1`. Might fix the issue, might not, but I will test your revised code now in any case.

Comment: Looks like I overlooked that it was actually working... For some reason, the first listing was the same on each page, but the rest were different!